# Styling an SVG that's generated via JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I have an SVG that is generated with some JS.

I want to style the following element...

```
<g class="slice">
    <path fill="#ff7f0e" ></path>
    <text>Better luck next time!</text>
</g>
```

I've tried using...

```
g.slice {
    background: url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/730/SVG_Stroke_Linecap_Example.png);
    background-color: blue;
}
```

yet it has no effect. I've read about using `<defs>` and defining a pattern only It isn't an option with the output being generated via the JS.

Can anybody think of a solution?

Comment: Why isn't defining a pattern an option with JS generated output? Just make the JS output a pattern too.

Answer (score 2):

`background` and `background-color` are CSS properties for styling HTML elements. They are not valid for SVG elements.

SVG is a totally different technology.  Things don't work the same as HTML.  A `<g>` is nothing like a `<div>`, which is what you appear to be thinking.

If you wanted to have a coloured background for the elements inside group "slice" you would need to add a coloured rectangle to that group.

Something like:

```
<g class="slice">
    <rect x="<something>" y="<something>" width="<something>" height="<something>"
          class="background"/>
    <path fill="#ff7f0e" ></path>
    <text>Better luck next time!</text>
</g>

.background {
    fill: blue;
}
```